# Using MultiView and View in .net giving following error

Tags: asp.net, view

I am just testing multiview and View in my application and i am getting this error:

```
    Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'NextView' and no extension method 'NextView' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 24:                 THIS IS VIEW 1 . HAVE A LOOK ! iTS COOL BECAUSE OF C#.<br />
Line 25:                 <br />
Line 26:                 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="nEXT" OnClick="NextView" />
Line 27:                 <br />
Line 28:                 <br />

Source File: c:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsAzure2\TestCRole\Default.aspx    Line: 26 


Show Detailed Compiler Output:




   C:\Program Files\IIS Express> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Web.Entity.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\6e2beae7\65ed30e8_a086ce01\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\f8024e97\5ae96ae9_a086ce01\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\c3d9637a\918f4ce5_a086ce01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\0ef8a197\0002c02e_8037ce01\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\8cf78885\661236e9_a086ce01\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\0f135984\0002c02e_8037ce01\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.StorageUtility.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\9af94552\fd6f8ee7_a086ce01\Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\6a1d662a\440d81e6_a086ce01\AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\c173128b\d527edf3_a086ce01\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\fd6a6bde\883f6ef3_a086ce01\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\f48702fd\d6c260f4_a086ce01\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary A

SP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\013c6eb1\224a2af3_a086ce01\System.Spatial.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\App_Web_4ujcsvkd.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\d0dfc6a8\b31683e8_a086ce01\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\ea4ee4b1\08e025e6_a086ce01\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\41a8bdc9\6cc349e6_a086ce01\AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\fe7db49b\dc9293e5_a086ce01\System.Web.Providers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\b65b2946\e442abeb_a086ce01\Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\86ffbcaf\1a0b54e5_a086ce01\WebGrease.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\b859b3a5\ff2db5e8_a086ce01\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\App_global.asax.al4ak3u5.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\228bb4bd\6145e1e9_a086ce01\EntityFramework.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\67c861d6\58ca9b56_a286ce01\TestCRole.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\4f582235\3a8a04e7_a086ce01\Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\23c9d56d\58494aeb_a086ce01\Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\bb0ccab2\67d8b9f3_a086ce01\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\991d36a5\dbdde9e8_a086ce01\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\assembly\dl3\171e3f4f\3f887ceb_a086ce01\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\App_Web_zxhsulcz.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /win32res:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\zxhsulcz.res" /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror-  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\App_Web_zxhsulcz.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\App_Web_zxhsulcz.1.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\App_Web_zxhsulcz.2.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\App_Web_zxhsulcz.3.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6364a8aa\d5e0a0cd\App_Web_zxhsulcz.4.cs"


Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929
```

Can anyone explain what i am doing wrong ? or what that error even means..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer now for my question.

I just need to use Protected for my classes used for button.

That's It.. :P